# Find the Norm of an Ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\theta=\sqrt[3]{2}$. I am asked to find $N(5,\theta+2)$ in $\mathbb{A}\cap\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. I know the answer is $5$ based on Dedekind's Prime Factorization Theorem but this is something I learned outside of class so I'm not allowed to quote this. I know one way of doing this question is to find an integral basis for $\mathbb{A}\cap\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, which will turn out to be $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$ but this method will be extreme tedious to write up because $\text{disc}(\mathbb{Q}(\theta))=-108=-2^23^3$. Can someone suggest a simpler way of doing this?

I have tried to count the number of equivalence classes of $\mathbb{A}\cap\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ modulo $(5,\theta+2)$ but I can't seem to find an argument without finding the integral basis.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Because $5$ is in your ideal, and the ideal generated by $5$ alone will have norm $5^3$, you know that the answer will be one of $1,5,25$ or $125$. Can you rule out the cases 1,25 and 125? Knowledge of the discriminant tells you that the free abelian group generated by $1,\theta,\theta^2$ has index $m$ in the ring of integers that is a factor of six. Looks like that won't disturb powers of five, but I need to convince myself, too :-)

Comment: Ruling out 1 and 125 is obvious. The question also asked me to find $N(5,\theta^2+3\theta-1)$ which happens to be 25, but I have no way of proving this without using integral basis. So I have no idea how to show $N(5,\theta+2)\not=25$. =(

Comment: Let $O$ be the ring of integers and $R$ the ring with $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$. The discriminant tells you that $[O:R]\mid 6$. Let $I=5O+(\theta+2)O$ and $J=5R+(\theta+2)R$. You can immediately tell that $[R:J]=5$. You also know that the only prime factors of $[I:J]$ and $[O:R]$ can be two and three. Therefore there exist integers $a,b$ such that
$$[O:I]=2^a3^b[R:J].$$ Because both $[R:J]$ and $[O:I]$ must be powers of 5, you can conclude that $[O:I]=5$, no?

Comment: The discriminant of what? I do not know the discriminant of anything because I have not proven that $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$ is an integral basis, so I have no way of computing an integral basis.

Comment: The discriminant of the polynomial $x^3-2$, which equals the discriminant of the ring $R$. We have the result
$$disc(O)[O:R]^2=disc(R).$$

Comment: Unfortunately, discriminant of a polynomial is not covered so I'm not allowed to use it. My professor banned me from using anything that is not taught inside the course. =(

Comment: You have somewhere done the formula for the discriminant of a cubic $p(x)=x^3+ax+b$, right? It is $-(4a^3+27b^2)$.

Comment: Ok, but can you calculate the discriminant of the ring $R$?

Comment: To calculate the discriminant of a ring, I need the integral basis which I'm trying to avoid having to prove. It sucks to be given powerful tools that I'm not allowed to use.

Comment: Well, $R$ has integral basis $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$ by its definition.

Comment: How do you know that is true?

Comment: I was referring to the ring $R$ I defined a few comments up. It is not necessarily the ring of integers, it may be smaller.

Comment: Oh okay, I see.

Comment: It's 3am here. I will continue this in the morning. Good night.

Comment: Sleep well. I'm off to work anyway :-)

Comment: I have come up with a solution that uses the fact that if $J\subset I$ then $N(I)\leq N(J)$. I haven't attempted to prove this fact but it seems to be make sense.